# Only render translated nodes, prevent rendering of base language node

Tags: 8, entities, nodes, i18n-l10n

Having an entity reference, **Drupal 8** automatically renders the base language of a referenced entity if it isn't translated yet. Is there a way to globally prevent that? So if there is ContentType1 referencing ContentType2, both have a default language of `en-gb`. Translating ContentType1 to `de-de` will by default still show ContentType2's `en-gb` node unless I manually translate it or change a thing.

What I currently do is comparing the current page language `\Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();` with the current node language `$variables['node']->language()->getId();` and return an empty `node.html.twig`.

Is there a better solution? Especially when you have multiple `node.twig.html`

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about it is to disable language fallback mechanism in Drupal. Although there are 3 different modules which handle language fallback priority, none of them provide such functionality.
However, the module [Disable Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_language) allows admin to disable an entire language entirely without deleting the content itself.
I think you can use its code to implement an EventSubscriber which checks whether the node has a translation for the current site language then return a NotFoundException in this case. This will cover direct node access.
I'm not entirely sure how to deal with nodes loaded via DB. I think you can use [hook_entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/8.6.x) for this case.